# If statements without defining variables (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

How would I go about writing a simple set of nested if statements that **check the user input** and **don't require variables**?

For example (**pseudo-code**)

```
If userinput == "A":
    print("great, next?")
    if userinput == "A"
       print("great, your second letter is A, again")
       print("what's next?")
       if userinput == "A"
           print("you have a lot of creativity")
       elif userinput == "B"
           print("so, so far we have A, A, B, interesting")
       elif userinput == "C"
           print("A C!")
    elif userinput = "B"
       print("love the choice of B")
    else:
       print("I can't accept that, you needed to type 'A' or 'B'")
Else:
    print("you needed to type 'A'")
```

I want this to be able to continue dozens of levels deep.

Edit: I've corrected the p-c with elif, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: what is wrong with this? you can use `input("some text: ")` to take user input

Comment: You need a variable if you want to test it multiple times.

Comment: Why? This logic strongly suggests a different (more robust) structure is in order.  Please clarify the use case as there is likely a better approach.

Comment: Just for the information; the `if userinput = "B"` line is a syntax error

Comment: You should use `elif` for your second `if` at the same level.

Comment: @Avijeet It's pseudo-code, so there isn't really any syntax.

Comment: You could use the new `match` statement to test the same value against multiple values.

Comment: The use case is a conversational tool which only accepts specific inputs. What structure could be implemented otherwise? I believe I would only need a Python-appropriate replacement for 'userinput', unfortunately it's not recognizing input("some text: ") as valid

Answer (score 2):

To answer the exact question you asked, where you want to prompt the user for input in a way that "doesn't require variables" (by which I assume you mean that you don't want to bind any values to variable names):

```
{"A": lambda: (
    print("great, next?"),
    {"A": lambda: (
        print("great, your second letter is A, again"),
        print("what's next?"),
        {"A": lambda:
            print("you have a lot of creativity"),
         "B": lambda: print("so, so far we have A, A, B, interesting"),
         "C": lambda: print("A C!")
        }.get(input(), lambda: None)()),
     "B": lambda: print("love the choice of B"),
    }.get(input(), lambda: print("I can't accept that, you needed to type 'A' or 'B'"))()
),
"B": None
}.get(input(), lambda: print("you needed to type 'A'"))()
```

Save that to a file called `bad_dont_do_this.py` and then run it like:

```
$ python bad_dont_do_this.py
```

and type in your A's, B's, and C's.

Unless you're trying to win a bet or something, this is not good code and you shouldn't use this approach.  I'd be interested to hear why you can't use variables in your code.  You almost certainly want to ask another question where you're more clear about the higher level goals you're trying to achieve.

Edit: this is the output I get when I follow my directions:

```
C:\>python bad_dont_do_this.py
A
great, next?
A
great, your second letter is A, again
what's next?
A
you have a lot of creativity

C:\>python bad_dont_do_this.py
A
great, next?
A
great, your second letter is A, again
what's next?
B
so, so far we have A, A, B, interesting

C:\>python bad_dont_do_this.py
A
great, next?
B
love the choice of B

C:\>python bad_dont_do_this.py
Z
you needed to type 'A'
```

---

Based on your comment about not wanting to create new variable names for all of the nested conditions, you can consider doing something like the following:

```
x = input("> ")
if x == "A":
    print("great, next?")
    x = input("> ")
    if x == "A":
       print("great, your second letter is A, again")
       print("what's next?")
       x = input("> ")
       if x == "A":
           print("you have a lot of creativity")
       elif x == "B":
           print("so, so far we have A, A, B, interesting")
       elif x == "C":
           print("A C!")
    elif x == "B":
       print("love the choice of B")
    else:
       print("I can't accept that, you needed to type 'A' or 'B'")
else:
    print("you needed to type 'A'")
```

Note how `x` gets bound to the new user input in each branch of the if statements.  Like another commenter mentioned, if you are able to use a new-enough Python version, you can probably make this even more succinct with the walrus (`:=`) and match features.

Comment: That's fair. I'm playing around with emulating a conversation. Going by every tutorial I can find it appears I would need to reference a variable for every instance of user input, but when I'm not going to do anything with the data, I would only be naming these variables e.g. userinput1, userinput2. There could be dozens upon dozens of branches in theory, so I was looking for a generic 'userinput' to reuse.

Comment: This does not work unfortunately and has skipped to the last line. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @GameAnalysis *you aren't actually supposed to use this*

Comment: @GameAnalysis, yes, please don't use this unless you're in some really wacky situation.  I'm just having a bit of fun answering the exact question as I understood it.  I didn't test every branch, but I did paste in the output for a few runs.   If you're trying to do something serious, please ignore this answer and ask a new question with more background on the exact problem you're trying to solve.  Asking for a solution "without variables" is probably not what you really want, for example.

Comment: @GameAnalysis, sorry just saw your first comment.  You can "reuse" variables if you want to.  So you can say `x = input()` and then condition on `x` with `if` and `elif` tests.  Within those blocks, you can rebind `x` to a new value by writing `x = input()` again.  I'll update my answer with this approach.  This saves you from having to invent unnecessary variable names.